# Why X-axis values of a histogram disappear when specifying the breaks?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, raster

trying to plot a raster file using ggplot2   but the x axis values disappeared. I am grateful to any help

```
conne <- file("C:complete.bin","rb")
sd <- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
y <-t(matrix((data=sd), ncol=1440, nrow=720))
f <- hist(y, breaks=30,main="sm")
f$counts <-f$counts/sum(f$counts)
dat <- data.frame(counts= f$counts,breaks = f$mids)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = breaks, y = counts, fill =counts)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",alpha = 0.8)+
    xlab("Bi")+ 
    ylab("Frequency")+
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(20, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0, end = 1)[1:12]))+
    ggtitle("2010")+
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20))+
    theme(axis.title.y =  element_text(size = 20))+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2.5)))+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(seq(-0.5,0.5,0.1)),labels = seq(seq(-0.5,0.5,0.1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe try to remove the last line of your code.

Comment: You could also let ggplot to make the histogram for you: `ggplot(sd, aes(x = y)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill = ..count..))`

Comment: Run `seq(seq(-0.5,0.5,0.1))` and verify if that's _really_ what you meant to do. I'm guessing it isn't.

Comment: You are attempting to mix discrete and continuous. Histograms are of necessity discrete on their "x-axis". You are also labeling with values that do not agree with the breaks. It _should_ not "work". After clarifying why this would make sense ... pick a more appropriate method for annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @joran hinted, change the last line to

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.5,0.5,0.1),labels = seq(-0.5,0.5,0.1))
```

(I think the `labels` argument is probably redundant in this case.)  When you run `seq(seq(...))` what are you getting is the result of running `seq` on a vector, i.e. a vector of indices from 1 to the length of your vector (11).  This vector doesn't overlap the x range of your data at all, so the breaks disappear ...